# Is there a way to make a SharePoint sharing link into an attachment or something nicer instead of an URL in Power Automate?

Tags: sharepoint-online, power-automate, flow, sharing-link

Just as the title states can I make a sharing link to SharePoint look nicer in an email which I am automating through Power Automate?
[image]

Comment: Can you share the screenshot of flow you are using currently? Add the screenshot by editing your original question/post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get the file itemid by path or get files.
This is obtained via path:
[image]

Then create sharelink based on itemid:
[image]
Finally send mail:
[image]

Note the insertion of the   tag

The result：

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, much appreciated!